# CSS elements are overlapping when resizing window

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know I have created a similar post before this, but I did not get an answer so I thought I'd give it another shot and see if anyone can help me out here. Basically, my CSS elements are overlapping (specifically the login box, vertical line and side text classes). I tried using percentages to avoid this problem but it did not really workout.

And if I use media queries the resizing would not be accurate on a computer web browser application, right? If I were to use media queries, how would I know what to set the minimum width to if the user is resizing the window browser?

Here is my code that I have so far...

```css
*:focus {
  outline: none;
}

body {
  background: #ced4da;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.login-box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 33%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 12.5px;
}

.email-input-field {
  position: relative;
}

.password-input-field {
  position: relative;
}

.email-input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 4px;
  padding: 9px 8px;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.password-input-field i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 4px;
  padding: 9px 12px;
  color: darkgrey;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.email-input-field input:focus+i,
.password-input-field input:focus+i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.login-box .email-input-field,
.password-input-field {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login-box input[type="email"],
input[type="password"] {
  border: none;
  background: white;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 83%;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"] {
  border: none;
  background-color: #3DBB96;
  color: white;
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #07A973;
}

::placeholder {
  color: grey;
}

.vertical-line {
  border-left: 1px solid darkgrey;
  width: 1px;
  height: 170px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.side-text {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 63%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  line-height: 100%;
}

.side-text p {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.side-text h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="login-box">
  <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="email-input-field">
      <input type="email" name="emailPost" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off">
      <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="password-input-field">
      <input type="password" name="passwordPost" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
      <i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="vertical-line"></div>
<div class="side-text">
  <h1> COLD OPS </h1>
  <p> ADMINISTRATION PANEL </p>
</div>
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<head>
    <title> Admin Login </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Login.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>
        *:focus {
            outline: none;
        }

        body {
            background: #ced4da;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        .login-box {
            width: 300px;
            height: 170px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
            color: white;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 12.5px;
        }

        .email-input-field {
            position: relative;
        }

        .password-input-field {
            position: relative;
        }

        .email-input-field i {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 4px;
            padding: 9px 8px;
            color:darkgrey;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .password-input-field i {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 4px;
            padding: 9px 12px;
            color:darkgrey;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .email-input-field input:focus + i, .password-input-field input:focus + i {
            color:dodgerblue;
        }

        .login-box .email-input-field, .password-input-field {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .login-box input[type="email"], input[type="password"] {
            border: none;
            background: white;
            height: 40px;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 83%;
            padding-left: 50px;
        }

        .login-box input[type="submit"] {
            border: none;
            background-color: #3DBB96;
            color: white;
            outline: none;
            height: 40px;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: lighter;
        }

        .login-box input[type="submit"]:hover {
            background-color: #07A973;
        }

        ::placeholder {
            color: grey;
        }

        .splitter {
            border-left: 1px solid darkgrey;
            width:1px;
            height: 170px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0 20px;
        }

        .side-text {
            width: 200px;
            height: 80px;
            line-height: 100%;
        }

        .side-text p {
            font-weight: lighter;
        }

        .side-text h1 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        @media (max-width: 640px) {
            .wrapper {
                flex-direction: column;
            }
            .splitter {
                border-top: 1px solid darkgrey;
                height:1px;
                width: 170px;
                margin: 20px 0;
            }
            .side-text {
                text-align: center;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class = "login-box">
        <form action = "Login.php" method = "POST">
            <div class = "email-input-field">
                <input type = "email" name = "emailPost" placeholder = "Email" autocomplete = "off">
                <i class = "fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
            </div>
            <div class = "password-input-field">
                <input type = "password" name = "passwordPost" placeholder = "Password" autocomplete = "off">
                <i class = "fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
            </div>
            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class = "splitter"></div>
    <div class = "side-text">
        <h1> COLD OPS </h1>
        <p> ADMINISTRATION PANEL </p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: although this may answer the question it's better to explain what you have done, from what the op said he clearly doesn't have a good grasp of media quires.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! :) So when the width is 640px or less it is shown in a column view? If it's not too much of a hassle can you please clean to me what the wrapper is? Is it just to change it to a column view when the pixel width is less than 640px? Thank you again!

Comment: Yes, you are right regarding the first question.
I use .wrapper to make view - full screen, also it has `display: flex;` and I don't want to set this styles on body tag for you, to avoid problems in case you will have extra work on your page

Comment: @IvanBisultanov Oh got it! Thanks for the explanation! :) Sorry, one last thing. I noticed that the class splitter isn't centered in the page exactly and that you removed the padding from it I think and added a margin to split the side text and login-box classes. How can I center the splitter to the center of the page horizontally? Thanks again! :)

Comment: Actually, don't know all requirements, but I believe this will help you.
.side-text { width: 300px; }

so the form & text parts should have the same width

Comment: @IvanBisultanov Perfect! Thank you so much! :) I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: @OmarDajani Always happy to help!